# How to square only the positive numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, math, int

I am trying to only square the positive numbers in a list. But when I try the code it squares all of them

```
def squarethis(numbers):
for n in numbers:
    if n > 0:
        return[n ** 2 for n in numbers]

print(squarethis([1, 3, 5, -81]))
```

Why does it square all numbers? The if-statement should filter the negatives out right?

Comment: question: why only negative numbers? square numbers are all positive so it shouldn't matter

Comment: Also you're essentially looping twice as you have a list comprehension in your for loop `return[n ** 2 for n in numbers]`

Comment: Notice that you have a list comprehension inside your for loop. It squares all of the numbers on the first pass of the for loop and returns that result. Skip the loop and just do `return [n**2 for n in numbers if n >= 0]`.

Comment: You're returning the entire list squared the moment a positive number is reached. You're not modifying the list.

Comment: @EdChum How do you know enough about the problem space to know its okay to square the negative numbers?

Comment: @tdelaney I did ask the OP why, I'm pointing out that it's fine to square integer values negative or not

Comment: @EdChum its only fine if your problem space says its fine. This is likely a homework assignment to teach filtering but there are many reasons to filter data. Squaring the negative looses information (that it was negative) and may be totally inappropriate for this particular program.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question. I am sure your original code is indented properly because it would raise a syntax error otherwise, but it will make your question clearer (and will be good practice!) to make sure the indentation is correct in your question as well ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a single list comprehension:

```
def squarethis(numbers):
    return [n ** 2 for n in numbers if n > 0]
```

What you are doing in the code your provided is checking if the first value in `numbers` is `> 0`, and if it is, returning your list comprehension with every value in `numbers` squared. Instead, you can do your filtering in the list comprehension itself, and return the list.

Answer (score 0):

A purely functional alternative ->

```
>>> map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x > 0, [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]))
[1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is quite a bit less efficient than the equivalent list comprehension due to the use of user-defined functions with `map` and `filter`.

Comment: Definitely is, however, is an interesting alternative nonetheless.